# SQLAlchemy: if just using core, and not the ORM, can I get a different class back than RowProxy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This really boils down to questions like [Can I assign values in RowProxy using the sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588375/can-i-assign-values-in-rowproxy-using-the-sqlalchemy) and their recommendation of just casting results to `dict`.

I want to assign values on the result rows and I am mostly using SQLAlchemy, with raw sql, for its brilliant multi-RDBMS support (with some use of introspection too).

Basically, a lot of my selects look like

```
results = connection.execute("select foo from bar where zoom = ?", binds)
results = [dict(row) for row in results]
```

But it would be even better if I could just specify a different result class, like plain old `dict`, either when initiating the connection, or on execute.  Probably faster too, as well as more convenient.

I took a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html and at the source of **sqlalchemy.engine.result** and it looks like `_process_row` on the `ResultProxy` classes is where `RowProxy` gets registered.  But I saw no way to modify that through the API.

I realize this an edge case compared to ORM use, but I really can't use ORM in my case.  It's perfectly fine if it's not possible, just don't want to overlook something already included.